# Magento 1.9 Importing products from csv error

Tags: magento-1.9

Import products using csv to my store. It will display this errors. Thanks

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or      
update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails   
(`mglab`.`catalog_product_entity`, CONSTRAINT  
`FK_CAT_PRD_ENTT_ATTR_SET_ID_EAV_ATTR_SET_ATTR_SET_ID` FOREIGN KEY  
(`attribute_set_id`) REFERENCES `eav_attribute_set` (`attribute_set_id`) 
ON DELE), query was: INSERT INTO catalog_product_entity       (entity_id,entity_type_id,attribute_set_id,type_id,sku,has_options,required_options,created_at,updated_at) VALUES ('','4','','simple','UF-222','0','0','2016-10-28 03:54:53','2016-10-28 03:54:53') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE entity_type_id=VALUES(entity_type_id),attribute_set_id=VALUES(attribute_set_id), type_id=VALUES(type_id), sku=VALUES(sku),has_options=VALUES(has_options),required_options=VALUES(required_options), created_at=VALUES(created_at), updated_at=VALUES(updated_at);
```

Comment: check the attribute set which set in csv file is avilable into the system where you can try to import.

Comment: share a screenshot of excel.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. Just a moment I'll create a screenshot of the excel file

Comment: Hi @DhirenVasoya in the csv file there is no attribute set column.

Comment: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-uMtxYpGnaRI/WBLSzSU-GeI/AAAAAAAAAR0/gyrvnwcc3IASPqtU8Bmh7HwavoIsbPZngCL0B/h480/excel.png

Answer (score 0):

Hello I found the fix.

It  appears that attribute_set was missing in the column in my csv file.

Thanks for the efforts guys.